# How to rip movie dvd with copy protection?

Tags: dvd, ripping

I'm trying to rip a movie dvd to an ISO image. When I try to copy it, at the beginning it seems like everything is working fine. But when it reaches around 650MB (I guess that's the start of the main movie which is copy protected), it becomes unbelievably slow or the program isn't reacting anymore. I've tried it with dd, ddrescue, mkisofs and K3b.

I'm using a LG GP08NU6W as an external dvd drive and I'm running Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

[`dvdbackup`](http://dvdbackup.sourceforge.net/) can take care of most of this – it extracts a unencrypted copy of a DVD’s disk contents, following the standard DVD layout. It doesn’t produce an ISO image but one can be generated using `genisoimage` using the directory layout produced by `dvdbackup`.

Comment: With dvdbackup it's the same like with all the other programs. It copies the menu just fine but when it reaches the main title it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That’s strange, it works fine for me (but I don’t have the same drive as you).

Comment: Also strage is that I hear it reading a few seconds but then it stops. Maybe my drive is somehow detecting that I'm trying to copy a copy protected file and the stops reading to prevent that but I don't know how it should do that.

Comment: Right, reading a DVD to copy it should look the same to the drive as reading it to display it... Can you *watch* DVDs using the drive?

Comment: Yes, watching DVDs works fine. I also tried it with another drive and I got the same result. Then I tried to copy it file-by-file and it turned out that some files are broken and can't be read, played or copied. Maybe this is some different kind of copy protection and the IFO files are programmed to ignore those files. But I havent managed to copy the DVD without those files. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tool that can understand the streams, and extract only the true ones. Copy protection can include unreadable sectors in parts of the disk that should never need to be read, and it seems that's what you've got here.

As a result you can't simply copy to an ISO image; you'd need to extract the true data and build a new unencrypted DVD image. Or just generate an MP4